# How can I get ReSharper to admit that the function parameters have the correct type?

Tags: typescript, resharper

I'm using ReSharper 10.0.1 with TypeScript 1.7 and AngularJS 1.3.6. ReSharper is complaining about this section, with the error "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: parameter type mismatch. Parameter 's' should have type assignable to 'string', but it has type 'any'.

```
items: $ServerTypes.IServerType[] = [a_set_of_Schema.state_objects_with_$type];
var queue: Schema.state[] = [items[0]];
state.transition.forEach((t: Schema.transition) => {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(t.target))) { // ** Error here at t.target
        queue.unshift($scope.getStateById(t.target)); // ** Same error at t.target
    }
});
```

The type of Schema.transition and Schema.state is fairly straightforward:

```
declare module MyStuff.Thing.Whatsit.Widget.Whatever.Schema
    export interface state {
        'id': string
        'transition': transition[]
    }
    export interface transition {
        'event': string;
        'Items': $ServerTypes.IServerType[]; // an object with a $type property
        'name': string;
        'target': string;
    }
}
```

I use an import statement to shorten the module name. (This import is in a _references.ts file that I've referenced in every file.)

```
import Schema = MyStuff.Thing.Whatsit.Widget.Whatever.Schema;
```

The oddity about this is that Schema.state has one additional property most of the time: $type. This property allows the ASP.Net on the server to convert a JSON blob into correctly-typed C# classes on the server. The place where I find my Schema.state objects is an array of $ServerTypes.IServerType, where IServerType looks like this:

```
declare module $ServerTypes {
    export interface IServerType {
        $type: string
    }
}
```

I want to keep the $type out of the Schema.state definition, because it's a C# implementation detail that (mostly) doesn't belong in the TypeScript code, and I have to create some Schema.state objects in the TypeScript code occasionally. There's a set of helper classes that will add the $type when needed. (Due to a JSON.NET limitation, $type must be the *first* property in the JSON object. The TypeScript code should *not* have to care about this.)

The point is: **t.target is a string. Both parseInt and $scope.getStateById take a single string parameter. Why does ReSharper think that t.target isn't a string?** Everything compiles and runs just fine; ReSharper's complaints are the only trouble

I want to use ReSharper, because it helps me keep my code clean. But if it's going to give false errors, then I'm going to have to disable it. Is there a way to get it to stop complaining, so I can use ReSharper effectively? I'm having this same error in numerous places; it's not just one or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ReSharper 10.0.1 doesn't look very far to find imports. In my code, the import statement that shortens MyStuff.Thing.Whatsit.Widget.Whatever.Schema to Schema was in a common-project file, about three `<reference>`s away. So this is the culprit:

```
import Schema = MyStuff.Thing.Whatsit.Widget.Whatever.Schema;
```

Using the long form every time forced ReSharper to think of my objects as being the correct type, rather than "any", and I stopped getting ridiculous errors along the lines of "string is not string, you need to use string." Unfortunately, this means that my code is now pointlessly verbose, because the server C# code (which the class names are ultimately based on) has long namespaces.

After some more fiddling, I discovered that the import statements must be in the same file where they're going to be used, and that they have to be *inside* the module definition or else they'll all conflict with each other. So I can have my shortened names as long as I create an import statement for each file.

(This whole problem happened because the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 is capable of looking through the whole solution for types, but ReSharper is still limited to looking within a single project. I now have a small pile of minor hacks devoted to informing ReSharper about the things that Visual Studio already knows about.)

Comment: More than a year on and ReSharper is still rubbish when it comes to Typescript, annoying!

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine in Standard TypeScript :

```
export interface transition {
    'event': string;
    'name': string;
    'target': string;
}

var t:transition;
parseInt(t.target);
```

Note that Resharper (JetBrains) have their *own* implementation of TypeScript so their analysis might not yeild the same result as the *standard* TypeScript.

## Potential Fix:

Don't use *quoted member declarations*. I.e. try the following :

```
export interface transition {
    event: string;
    name: string;
    target: string;
}

var t:transition;
parseInt(t.target);
```

## PS

Just sharing convention. Prefer `Transition` over `transition` for interface / type declarations

> But if it's going to give false errors, then I'm going to have to disable it. Is there a way to get it to stop complaining, so I can use ReSharper effectively? I'm having this same error in numerous places; it's not just one or two

Wait for a resharper update. Till then you can switch off resharper for TypeScript and still use it for C# etc.

Comment: I agree, the class names are a bit wonky. They're generated by a script that grovels the C# classes on the server side. Those C# classes are, in turn, generated by an XML spec. It's turtles all the way down. As for the type declaration, I've expanded the question to mention the IServerType type than we're trying to quietly use behind the scenes.